# Working with multiple recordsets returned from a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

Inspired by [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/31de09bb-5bd9-423a-a960-fbad48d2f653/reading-stored-procedure-recordsets), I would like to issue the following command:

```
exec sp_spaceused
with result sets(
(database_name varchar(128)
,database_size varchar(128)
,[unallocated space] varchar(128)
)
,
(reserved varchar(128)
,data varchar(128)
,index_size varchar(128)
,unused varchar(128)
)
)
```

and then get the results back into memory variables so that I can do some logic with them.

Q: How do I say something like:

```
DECLARE @DatabaseName Varchar(128) = database_name
DECLARE @IndexSize Varchar(128) = index_size
```

Comment: Don't get distracted by the fact that I'm using sp_spaceused. I just grabbed it as a generic stored procedure that returns multiple recordsets.

Comment: What information in that link, or any of the 20 similar questions already posted and answered here on S.O., did not answer your question? Also, there is nothing in your example that shows multiple result sets. Can you please clarify. In general, if you want to capture proc results (regardless of how many result sets), your options are: insert into #tmp EXEC, OPENQUERY, and running from a SQLCLR stored procedure where you can intercept the results.